# Find Objects based on child object in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

So i have following Entitys/Tables for a many to many relation: **Satz**, **Track** and the mapping Table **Trackliste**

```
@Entity
class Track{
   // name, id
   @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Satz.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(
            name="trackliste", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TrackID"), 
   inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="SatzID"))
   private Set<Satz> saetze;
   // getters and setters
}


@Entity
class Trackliste {
   // id, trackid, satzid.
   // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Satz implements Serializable {
// id, titel, werkId, etc
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="saetze", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Track> tracks;
// getters and setters
}
```

and my repository looks like this:

```
public interface SatzRepository extends CrudRepository<Satz, Integer> {

    List<Satz> findById(int id);
    List<Satz> findByWerkId(int id);

    //Some query maybe?
    //List<Satz> findByTracks(String name);?

}
```

The Mapping works so far, when i call my Webservice it returns a json object and with the help of debugging i can see that the SatzRepository Set Contains objects of Track.

Now comes my question: How do i return a Satz based on the given Track name is this possible? Lets say i have a URL like this: `localhost:8080/rest/satz/trackname?name=%trackname%`

> If you need more Information please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a method in TrackRepository to find track by name then you can get satz list from track object.

```
public interface TrackRepository extends CrudRepository<Track, Integer> {

    Track findByName(String name);

}

@Transactional
public TrackServiceImpl implement TrackService{
    @AutoWired
    TrackRepository trackRepository;

    List<Satz> getSatzByTrackName(String name){
         Track track = trackRepository.getByName(name);

         return track != null ? track.getSaetze() : new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```